Which phrase is more appropriate, instead of "I don't know?"
I'm non native speaker. I usually have some problems with the suitable expressions used in different situations.
If I want to say I don't know, for example, which phrase is more appropriate?

In casual conversation, "I don't know" is unstressed and often (in American English) pronounced like "I dunno" or "iunno". In a business setting, you might say "I'm not sure, let me get back to you on that" or "Let me check with [person] to confirm". But nobody will think you're odd for "I don't know".

That would make for a nice answer, @Kaia :)

You can say "I know" --- "I'm not sure"  --- "I don't know".
You don't need "I really don't know", because "I don't know" is enough. Those three expressions should be enough for 99% of situations.
